# If a Cell Statement with Multiple Variables

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that I am trying to get an If statement to work. Col B is our hidden stock column and we have three variables that need to be return in COL C:

1. It has a quantity of 0-9 so the stock shows the exact number in that column
2. It has a quantity of 10 or more so it shows 10+
3. It is a product that has moved to a new model year sheet so it needs to return the test in the colum

So if Col B has stock of 8, Col C returns 8.
Col B has stock of 11, Col C returns 10+.
Col B has See 2023, Col C returns 2023.

Here are my two test formulas:
=IF(B2<=9,B2,"10+")
=IF(B3="see 2023",B3,B3)

[image]

I can not figure out how to combine them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and easy way of chaining IF functions is to nest them together.

```
=IF(B2="see 2023",B2,IF(B2<=9,B2,"10+"))
```

You can try using an OR function to combine the conditions.

```
=IF(OR(B2="see 2023", B2 <=9), B2, "10+"))
```

Comment: The Or 2nd answer worked, thank you!

Comment: If you would, click the checkmark beside my answer. See [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that was referred to me:

=if(istext(G36),G36,if(isbetween(G36,0,9),G36,if(G36>=10,"10+")))